# How to use iTunes to download songs and movie I purchased before?

Tags: itunes, iphone

I purchased songs and movies for my iPhone 3G, but after these 2 years, I am already using iPhone 4, and also changed to another computer.

The new computer also has iTunes, and also signed up with my Apple account, but I don't any easy way to download those songs and movies back to iTunes and to the iPhone 4.  How can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

All you really need to do is purchase them again, and you'll be notified that you have already purchased the item and will provide it to you for free.

Well that's what it does for apps so I think it works the same for iTunes Media.

Comment: but how can I remember all the 88 songs I purchased before?  Have to go search for them and buy them one by one again?

Comment: Maybe this link will help you out: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2727

Comment: I bought an audio book from iTunes before, so it is after 6 months and I want to hear it on the macbook as well, so I bought it again using the same account, but I am charged again and a receipt of $9.99 is sent to me again

Comment: I would suggest you email Apple about this, they shouldn't have charged you.

Answer (score 0):

I've had success calling Apple for this issue. The tech was able to restore my purchases and when I logged into iTunes I was able to download them all.